# Filter rows in dataframe in R after first instance of specific column value using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame in R with a lot of columns. One column contains an increasing sequence of numbers (column `x`), while another column contains certain values (column `y`)

**Example**
library(tidyverse)

```
df <- approx(seq(1,10,1), c(1,5,7,11,4,12,30, 20, 10, 9)) %>%
      as.data.frame()

plot(df)
```

[image]

**Problem**

I want to remove all rows in the dataframe using `dplyr`, starting when the first `y-value > 10`. I am able to do so using `dplyrs' filter function` *if* the function only crosses the line of `y=10` once. If the function crosses the line several times, however, I am not able to use it anymore.

**Attempt**

I have tried to use `dplyrs' slice` function:

```
df %>% slice(which(df$y<10)[1] )
```

but is sadly gives an error...

**Expected output**

```
df[-c(16:50),]
plot(df[-c(16:50),])
```

[image]

**Question**

How would I remove rows from a dataframe after the first instance of a value in a specific column using the Tidyverse collection of packages in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work:

```
df %>% 
    filter(row_number() <= first( which(df$y >10) ) -1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df_new <- df[1:min(which(df$y>10)-1),]
plot(df_new)
```